# can't import side effects in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have following code for routing (Routes.js):

```
export default (props) => {
    import(`../styles/${props.site}/theme.css`);

  return (
    <div>
      <Menu />
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact path="/"
          render={({ staticContext, match }) => {
            const site = staticContext
              ? staticContext.site
              : location.hostname.split(".")[0]
            return <UniversalComponent site={site} match={match} page="core/ToBeDeleted_Homepage" />
          }}
        />
...
...
```

First, I import css file with :

> "import(`../styles/${props.site}/theme.css`);"

Here, import side effects is used, so this is bounded to the applicaton that will work statically and import whenever ${props.site} variable is available.

Then, I render the app using everything inside "return(~~~)"

**This works if above code is written in .js file.
However, this does not work in typescript (.tsx file).**

**I get following error for having very similar code in .tsx file:**

```
[FLUSH CHUNKS]: Unable to find styles/localhost-theme-css in Webpack chunks. Please check usage of Babel plugin.
(node:28539) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module './undefined/theme.css'
```

It looks like it just returns before it finishes importing.. so this means for typescript, it does not work statically since it tries to import ${props.site} when ${props.site} variable isn't available and return error.

How can I fix this?

**my tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext", 
    "module": "ESNext", 
    "allowJs": true,    
    "jsx": "react",     
    "sourceMap": true, 
    "outDir": "dist", 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".vscode"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `require` instead of an `import` (since `import` can happen only at the *top level*). Also consider moving the logic outside the component.

```
const importStuff = (site) => {
   if (!site) return;

   require(`../styles/${site}/theme.css`);
};
```

Then simply inside component:

```
export default (props) => {
   importStuff(props.site);

   return (...);
}
```